# Adding a count to a number guessing game

Tags: javascript

So i have a basic number guessing game and it works fine, however I would like someone to show me how i could display the number of attempted guesses at the end of the game. Also would it be possible to show previous guesses at the end of the game like this? 
[image]

```
var canvas;
canvas = openGraphics();
var max;
max = 100;
var numberToGuess;
numberToGuess =  50; // will be changed to Math.floor( Math.random() * max ) + 1;
canvas.setFont("comic sans ms", "15px", Font.Bold);
canvas.drawString("Number Guessing Game!");
var guess;
guess = prompt( "Please input your guess 1-100" );


do {
// check previous guess and alert low/high message
if ( guess ) {
    if ( guess > numberToGuess ) {
        alert( "Your guess was too high: " + guess);
    }
    else if ( guess < numberToGuess ) {
        alert( "Your guess was too low: " + guess);
    }
}

guess = prompt( "Please input your guess 1-100" );
} while ( guess != numberToGuess );

alert( "You guessed correctly! " + guess );
canvas.paint();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, just keep a running track of the guesses. You should consider storing the actual input along with an indicator of whether it was high or low.

Start by declaring an empty array before the main loop

```
var guesses = [];
```

After the user has made a guess, add a new item to the list wiith the value, and whether it was high or low

```
if ( guess > numberToGuess ) {
    alert( "Your guess was too high: " + guess);
    guesses.push({value:guess,direction:'HIGH'});
}
else if ( guess < numberToGuess ) {
    alert( "Your guess was too low: " + guess);
    guesses.push({value:guess,direction:'LOW'});
}
```

Then at the end you can do 2 things

1. The number of guesses before correctly guessing the answer will be `guesses.length`
2. Enumerate `guesses` to output what each incremental guess was

So perhaps something along the lines of

```
canvas.drawString( "You guessed correctly! " + guess + " in " + guesses.length + " guesses");
for(var i=0;i<guesses.length;i++){
    canvas.drawString("Guess #" + (i+1) + ": " + guesses[i].value + " was " + guesses[i].direction);
}
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/3vjve7dL/

Comment: So i managed to display the number of incorrect guesses fine, but how exactly would I display these guesses? thanks for the help

Comment: @JohnSmith Create an array, store all the guesses entered by user in that array and then use the values in the array to display all guesses.

Comment: I attempted to do this and got: Guesses: [object Object],[object Object]  instead of the numbers?

Comment: @JohnSmith see update, ive added some code for the last bit you were struggling with.